# "yarn init" is not letting me start new project

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2

I installed Yarn Package Manager, so i can use with JavaScript.

But the problem is that when i enter the commands "yarn init", the following command prompt questions of creating your project name, description and etc.. does not follow. The only thing that shows in the terminal is the picture below. It just shows the name of the main folder, and the yarn package manager version.

[image]

I installed Yarn from the "command prompt" as "run administrator", through the commands "corepack enable". This is what the instructions are on the website for the latest versions, and is recommended way to install it from the website. It installs the latest version which is "yarn 3.2.4" .

i dont know why this is happening, i installed it as instructed. If you can provide solution / fix, would appreciate it.

below is the commands entered for installing it , and than starting new project (yarn init)

> corepack enable
>
> corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate
>
> yarn init

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting it to offer a much more detailed set of initialisation options, like the ones that the [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-init) and [`webpack-cli`](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#init) offers.

[classic yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/init/) offered a wizard to complete fields in the `package.json` file.

For later versions of yarn, `yarn init` only creates the minimum files and config required to initialise a yarn project (editorconfig, git, readme), but it doesn't offer a wizard to fill out the properties of the package.json file. Look at the docs for these tools and see if they fit your expectations.